# Access instance variable name within class

Tags: python

A little background - I am playing around with pygame, and want to create a dictionary of all Mob class instances' positions.

The way I see it:

```
human = Mob(pos)
mob_positions = {human : pos}
```

So every time I call `Mob.__init__()` I wanted to add a `pos` to `mob_positions` dict.

How do I access current instance variable name? Or is it extremely wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current instance variable is simply the first argument to the function. By convention it is named `self`.

Here's how I'd do things.

```
class Mob(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, mob_positions):
        self.pos = pos
        mob_positions[self] = pos
```

Answer (score 2):

Any bound method, including `__init__`, takes at least one parameter, usually named `self`, which is exactly what you are describing.

```
class Mob(object):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        mob_positions[self] = pos
```

Comment: Well, it takes however many parameters you define it to take. But it does take *at least* one.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I changed my wording.

Answer (score 2):

You have several ways to solve the problem. One of them is to pass mob_positions dictionary as argument to __init__.

```
class Mob(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, field=None):
        ...
        if field:
            field[self] = pos
```

Such notation allows you to place mobs on initialization or not (depending on what you're doing with mobs).

Comment: Right, I guess I was confused by result of the print, dictionary dump after using self was `{<Mob sprite(in 0 groups)>: pos}`. Thanks

Comment: <Mob sprite(in 0 groups)> is just a representation of your object. You just need to override __repr__() method of your mob class to receive some meningful representation (e.g. mob's name or mob's number, or smth. else you want to distinct mobs with).